Identify Local Regional Indian MP3 songs
I have an old collection of regional Indian mp3 songs. They are badly named and movie names and artist names are a mess. Is there any music player, plugin or some other method available in 24.04 that can identify the song and auto fetch details from the internet. Details like which movie or album the song is from, singer, music director, lyricist etc. Thanks.

MusicBrainz Picard worked for me. It is free, available on Flathub and worked well on regional songs.
